# Create a string/var/array from part of URL using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to populate a view based on part of a URL.

www.example.com/f/***objectID***
I  have a website with a view that loads based on the an ***objectID*** that is stored on parse.com

how can I extract/interpret "***objectID***" from the url to populate the /f/ view?

Comment: Do you want to get "objectID" string from "www.example.com/f/objectID" string?

Comment: Try to be more clear... What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Location_object) object. From there you just need some string methods.

```
var objectID = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will split the path into the fragments separated by `/` and [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) will retrieve the last one. Of course, if `objectID` may not always be the last segment, use the proper (0-based) index to retrieve it from array returned by `split`.

Another solution that may have better performance (shouldn't really make a difference for this use case), assumes that `objectID` is the last segment:

```
var objectID = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/axbVx/1)

Answer (score 0):

A regex would work or splitting the window.location.url:

```
var objectId = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/f\/(\w+)\/?/, '$1');
```

OR

```
var objectId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
```